# How to debug creation of async_hooks in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

We have a Node.js process that is crashing with thousands of errors like the following one:

```
# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202

# FILEHANDLE
node:internal/async_hooks:202
```

How do I trace when these `async_hooks` are created or otherwise get additional context to help debug the issue?

Essentially, I would like to know where those `async_hooks` that are hanging are initiated.